# get page id from title with wiki api none english

Tags: php, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I want get page id from wiki api vietnamese but when i try with url

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Trung%20%C4%90%C3%B4ng&prop=iwlinks&format=json
```

It can't show any thing

```
{"batchcomplete":"","query":{"pages":{"-1":{"ns":0,"title":"Trung \u0110\u00f4ng","missing":""}}}}
```

but when i use autosuggest in https://vi.wikipedia.org with link api

> [https://vi.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&format=json&formatversion=2&search=Trung%20Đông&namespace=0&limit=10&suggest=true](https://vi.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&format=json&formatversion=2&search=Trung%20%C4%90%C3%B4ng&namespace=0&limit=10&suggest=true)

Very lot result showing. How can I use action=query to get pageid with title on wiki vietnamese?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=info&titles=Main%20Page - it's no different in different languages

Comment: But this link not solve my problem. I need search in wiki việt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making the request to English Wikipedia instead of Vietnamese. Change the `en` to `vi` in your call and you will get results. See here:

https://vi.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Trung%20%C4%90%C3%B4ng&prop=iwlinks&format=json